# What is the easiest/most secure way to allow admins to become other users

Tags: php, mysql, html, security, admin

I have a control panel that allows admins to enter in certain search criteria about a user for moderation purposes. I almost afraid to admit this on here due to the backlashing I will surely receive, but on this page the admins can look up users passwords, so they can sign in as them for moderation purposes. So before you tear me a new one, let me say that I JUST finished hashing everyones password with `sha1` and unique salt!

That being said. I want to allow the admins to be able "become" a user or login as any user they choose.

I am looking for the easiest most secure method on how to do this. Please let me know any information you may need from me for you to be able to better answer my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to tag this as `bad-idea` but that's the only grief you'll get from me. :-)

Comment: Do the Admins needs to *be* the users, or just *be* the same role as the user?

Comment: Use a permissions system that'll allow admins to simulate user permissions, instead of giving admins access to user passwords. That's what phpBB does, and I think it's pretty cool.

Comment: very short on details actully needed to answer the question. probably changing values in session to match user, then again maybe not

Comment: @BoltClock - No passwords will be involved. It would involve inheriting user ids or something. @Jonathan Sampson - they just need to be able completely control their content. Erase certain posts etc. @CanSpice -  thanks for sparing me :)

Comment: @LightningWrist: I don't understand, don't you say the admins can look up user passwords so they can sign in as them?

Comment: Better to build a toolset for admins to make changes than let them just assume the role of that person. That way, they can make changes that the user cannot, and you can build in trackign to see what the admins do.

Comment: @BoltClock - I just hashed them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did this when I designed a high school site. I allowed staff to "proxy" in as another user. However, they would just enter the username, and then it would emulate a session for that user. They would never access the password at any point.

I had a `$USER` object and a `$SESSION` object. The `$USER` stored the currently active user, and the `$SESSION` stored the actual logged in user. Normally, they would be the same, but if a user was proxied in as another user, then `$USER->username` would not equal `$SESSION->username` and that would allow me to display a banner that said "You are proxied in as USER, to resume your session, click here"

Comment: ...And if you can detect the scenario, you can record its incidence, so you can track impersonations. Good call.

Comment: I completely understand the concept, but not really sure how to go about this structure wise. Your suggesting making a special page for only the admins that has a input box that they enter the user's name they want to login as and just submit and that will switch the session id's?

Comment: @LightningWrist - Yes, there is a page that only admins can see, and that has a textbox for them to enter the username they want to proxy as. Then I make a entry in a "proxies" table that says "admin X is proxied in as user Y" and then i use the `$SESSION->username` to check the proxy table, and if there is an entry in there, I use that username to create the `$USER` object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to circumvent any damage that an admin might do logged in as another user. In other words, at a technical level this isn't feasible. You are going to have to be sure you trust all your admins enough to give them this power.

I'm assuming this is the kind of security you are referring to. How to actually implement this behavior is a different question, and if that is what you meant, please correct me.

Comment: Ok, I personally would go with webdestroya's suggestion.